# RequireJS - difference between global require and module require

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have been wondering this for a long time, using RequireJS, is there actually a difference between the global require function and the require function that is passed to a module like so:

```
define(function (require) {
    // require === window.require ?
   return {};
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I asked the question of James Burke himself, author of RequireJS

> They are different, the main thing is that the local require knows how
>   to resolve './relative' dependency IDs relative to the module ID
>   asking for the dependency..
>
> The global one cannot do that. The global one has .config() on it, can
>   be used to configure the loader. Those are the main differences.

see: https://github.com/requirejs/requirejs/issues/1505